# Search criteria make required

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I am using a joomla component that has a search form with different criteria. However if nothing is entered in the search inputbox, and the search button is clicked, then it just shows all the results.

I need to make it so that if nothing is entered nothing is shown, or the red outline for inputbox required shows.

I have tried things like

```
input class="inputbox required"
```

which works on other forms I have but not this page. The code for the search inputbox is

```
criteria +='<div id="valueinput'+keynum+'" style="margin-right:10px;float:left;">';
                        criteria +='<input                      criteria +='<div id="valueinput'+keynum+'" style="margin-right:10px;float:left;">';
                        criteria +='<input class="inputbox" type="text" name="value'+keynum+'" id="value'+keynum+'" style="width:145px;"/>';
                    criteria +='</div>';
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just as a comment, showing all when you leave the search box empty is the behavior I expect when using a search form. You might want to consider the usability issue. Also which search are you using?

Answer (score 0):

use HTML5 [required](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Techniques/HTML5/Using_the_required_attribute_to_indicate_a_required_input_field) and [`formnovalidate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formnovalidate)

```
<input class="inputbox" 
type="text" formnovalidate name="value'+keynum+'" 
id="value'+keynum+'" style="width:145px;" required />
```

`formnovalidate` content `attributes` are **boolean attributes.** If present, they indicate that the form is not to be validated during submission.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" name="whatever" required />`

`required` is a [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-required-attribute) that is only ever true when present; older versions of IE need a bit more: `required="required"`

The above markup will trigger whatever native behavior the browser has built in. To go beyond that, or to support older browsers, you can add something like the jQuery Validation plugin: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

Comment: If you are using jform you can just say required no matter what.